# How can I redirect the parent page after OAuth 2 flow is complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, oauth

My current flow is such:

1. User clicks login to third party
2. Upon grant, the third party redirects to configured redirect uri with code
3. Forward code to backend to verify, etc.
4. Return success/failure

My frontend is coded to close the popup when the login is successful, but the parent page still just remains the same - standard login page. The goal would be to redirect that page.

I've tried to add an event listener on the window object, but it's not working.

```js
...
  const loginWindow = window.open(oAuthUrl,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=450')
  loginWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
    alert("new window closed");
  }
};
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm no OAUTH2 expert, but that code doesn't seem be enough information to help you with the complexities of oauth - effectively, you've show one meaningful line of code ... the first line ... the other 4 lines do nothing regarding oauth - now, as far as oauth goes, I'm fairly sure one line in the client (browser) is not going to be enough - there's also code required in *your* server for a start

Comment: Correct, however the question is about redirecting after the flow is complete. OAuth is hardly relevant.

Comment: Oh ... I must've misread the question - in that one useful line of code you posted, where is it you have a redirection that has no relevance to oauth

Comment: OAuth was added to provide context, however, I could've easily said "redirect parent after popup closes" and the solution would be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have something that seems to be working:

```
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/login', requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => window.close())
            .then(data => window.opener.location.replace("/"))
    }
```

`window.opener` allows you to access the parent window.